# Collision without CGRectIntersectsRect

Tags: ios, objective-c, collision-detection, cgrect

Im currently working on a game in xcode. My only problem is that I have complicated images and I only want the collision to be detected when the images touch each other not the actual bounding box. Is there any way that I can find a way to have collision detection between non-rectangular, complicated images without CGRectIntersectsRect.

If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What framework do you use? Is it Spritekit?

Comment: No, I've been on and off on this project for a while and started before sprite kit came out.

Comment: So what is it? Do you use just UI elements, for example UIImageView as sprites? or maybe Cocos2d?

Comment: I've Used UIImageViews

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend use smaller CGRect, subtract some offset from left/right and top/bottom edges and use CGRectIntersectRect.
You can also check is point interact with rect:

```
UIImageView *sprite = //Your sprite;
CGPoint point = CGPointMake(5,5);
BOOL isPointInsideSprite = [sprite pointInside:point withEvent:nil];
```

The second solution is more expensive but more precise.

Answer (score 0):

Er...okay, the thing that you're asking for is difficult.

To check if two images collide, you *could* render one image with an alpha mask of the other image, then check if the image is completely transparent...but that's *slow*, and collision detection needs to be *fast*.

It's also a little weird to have collision detection (a model level thing) depend on the sprites you're using (a view level thing). You update the art style and suddenly the game is way harder!

For this reason most games, even 3D games, use far simpler shapes to perform hit detection. Circular and rectangular collisions can be calculated far more efficiently than arbitrary bitmaps, so if you define a good bounding box (could be a rectangle or a circle or whatever), you can get much better performance.

Now...what if you actually need a bizarre shape, and circles and rectangles aren't good enough approximations? Well, you can define arbitrary polygon intersection algorithms...if that really is the way you need to go with your hit detection. But you still want to represent the hit detection area  with an abstract shape, not an image. If that is the way you need to go, research polygon intersection algorithms.